# Remove user from list when reaction_remove

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a function to store all the users that have responded in a string and output them.

Now I have the problem that if User1 gives a reaction and deletes it again, then User1 is still in the list.

```
        # hatch <type> <time>
        now = datetime.now()
        add_time = now + timedelta(minutes=int(args[2]))
        cur = add_time.strftime('%H:%M')
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Raid meldung von ' + str(message.author.display_name), color=discord.Color.green())
        embed.add_field(name='Raid Typ: ', value=args[1], inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Schluepft um: ", value=cur + "", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Interesse: ', value='Keine Zusagen', inline=False)

        channel = bot.get_channel(818662081531740163)
        mess = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        re_time = int(float(args[2])) * 60
        emoji_list = ['✅', '❌']
        for i in emoji_list:
            await mess.add_reaction(i)
        while True:
            users = ""
            try:
                reaction, user= await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=re_time)
                if str(reaction) == '✅':
                    mess = await channel.fetch_message(mess.id)
                    reaction_list = mess.reactions
                    react = get(mess.reactions, emoji='✅')
                    for reactions in reaction_list:
                        if str(reactions) == "✅":
                            if react and react.count <= 2:
                                user_list = [user async for user in reactions.users() if user != bot.user]
                                for user in user_list:
                                    users = users + user.mention + "\n"
                            else:
                                users = users + user.mention + "\n"
                    embed1 = discord.Embed(title='Raid meldung von ' + str(message.author.display_name), color=discord.Color.green())
                    embed1.add_field(name='Raid Typ: ', value=args[1], inline=True)
                    embed1.add_field(name="Schluepft um: ", value=cur + "", inline=True)
                    embed1.add_field(name='Interesse: ', value=users, inline=False)
                    await mess.edit(embed = embed1)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                break
        await asyncio.sleep(re_time)
        embed_end = discord.Embed(title='Raid meldung von ' + str(message.author.display_name), color=discord.Color.red())
        embed_end.add_field(name='Raid Typ: ', value=args[1], inline=True)
        embed_end.add_field(name="Schluepft um: ", value="Beendet", inline=True)
        await mess.edit(embed = embed_end)
        for i in emoji_list:
            await mess.clear_reactions()
```

i hope anyone have a solotion for my proplem

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating the list of users and updating the message whenever there's a ✅ reaction added to the message.
You need to either have logics for both [discord.on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add) and [discord.on_reaction_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_remove) events,
or you can just update the reaction list at an interval.

If you update the list of users at an interval, you will have an updated user list until your desired timeout.

```py
msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
while True:
    reactions = msg.reactions
    for react in reactions:
        if str(react) == "✅":
            users = [user async for user in reactions.users() if user != bot.user]
            break # if you don't care about other reactions
    # do stuff with your users
    async.sleep(1)  # or something else you see fit
```

Currently, there's a lot of redundancy in your code. Because I don't know the whole context or if some of them are intended or not, so I'll just stick with pointing out the absolute redundancies.

```py
mess = await channel.fetch_message(mess.id)
```

is not needed since you have the message object above. You can keep referencing it as long as the async method is still active.

```py
if str(reaction) == '✅':
    mess = await channel.fetch_message(mess.id)
    reaction_list = mess.reactions
    react = get(mess.reactions, emoji='✅')
    for reactions in reaction_list:
        if str(reactions) == "✅":
            if react and react.count <= 2:
```

You already have the ✅ Reaction object. You can play with this to fetch the users; no need to grab the list again, and definitely no need to iterate through the reaction list again.

I'm inclined to suggest you use the [discord.on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add) and [discord.on_reaction_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_remove) events.
It will be complicated because you have to keep juggling multiple events, but it will do what you want it to do efficiently.